# How to prevent all windows from floating (xmonad)

Tags: haskell, xmonad

In my system, xmonad floating windows are extremely buggy. Sometimes they appear out of the screen, under main windows. They may rapidly activate and deactivate, making xmonad freeze. Or they may just be impossible to click on. How do I force every window to appear as normal? That is to say, to disable floating entirely.

I don't know Haskell or any other functional language, so I would like a solution that is easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found solution for it. I was required to

```
import XMonad.Actions.SinkAll
```

and (e.g.) add keybinding for sinkAll

```
(...) `additionalKeys`
[
((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_f), sinkAll)
]
```

Now when I press mod+shift+f every floating window turn normal

Comment: Bit of a nitpick but I don't feel this answers the question, it's a workaround. Have you possible found a solution that does this automatically?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I moved from xmonad to i3, so I have not worked with it for some time. Maybe you should add a hook to every window

Answer (score 1):

None of my windows floats per default (I recall vaguely that gimp might be an exception here, and floats per default, but maybe I'm wrong). Also I think floating windows should never be "under" tiled windows (but maybe a floating window is "over" another floating or tiling window). If you've got a floating window and you want it to "appear as normal" press `mod-t`. Still, I'm wondering why your windows float - did you hold `mod` while dragging the window with the mouse?

[I can't help it ;)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPdDdC4go6c&t=1m32s)

Comment: But for example "saving" windows under ctrl+s are defaultly floating, aren't they?

Comment: @Ikciwor With firefox yes, sorry, I don't use that often. Do they really appear "behind" nonfloating windows?